# get the type of device (iPhone 4,5,6, iPod, iPad)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-simulator

Im trying to get the type of the device even in the IOS Simulator.
i have the code below:

```
NSLog(@"model: %@",[UIDevice currentDevice].model);
NSLog(@"description: %@",[UIDevice currentDevice].description);
NSLog(@"localizedModel: %@",[UIDevice currentDevice].localizedModel);
NSLog(@"name: %@",[UIDevice currentDevice].name);
NSLog(@"systemVersion: %@",[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion);
NSLog(@"systemName: %@",[UIDevice currentDevice].systemName);
```

but anyone of that lines return the type, but its returns only iPhone Simulator.
there's a way to get the type even in the IOS simulator?

Comment: The type *is* iPhone Simulator. If you want a real device type, then run it on a real device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this code for determining the device model

```
- (NSString *) platformString{

NSLog(@"[UIDevice currentDevice].model: %@",[UIDevice currentDevice].model);
NSLog(@"[UIDevice currentDevice].description: %@",[UIDevice currentDevice].description);
NSLog(@"[UIDevice currentDevice].localizedModel: %@",[UIDevice currentDevice].localizedModel);
NSLog(@"[UIDevice currentDevice].name: %@",[UIDevice currentDevice].name);
NSLog(@"[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion: %@",[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion);
NSLog(@"[UIDevice currentDevice].systemName: %@",[UIDevice currentDevice].systemName);
NSLog(@"[UIDevice currentDevice].batteryLevel: %f",[UIDevice currentDevice].batteryLevel);      
struct utsname systemInfo;
uname(&systemInfo);
NSLog(@"[NSString stringWithCString:systemInfo.machine encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]: %@",[NSString stringWithCString:systemInfo.machine encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
NSString *platform = [NSString stringWithCString:systemInfo.machine encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,1"])    return @"iPhone 1G";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,2"])    return @"iPhone 3G";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone2,1"])    return @"iPhone 3GS";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,1"])    return @"iPhone 4";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,2"])    return @"iPhone 4 CDMA";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone4,1"])    return @"iPhone 4S";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,1"])    return @"iPhone 5";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone7,2"])    return @"iPhone 6";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod1,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 1G";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod2,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 2G";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod3,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 3G";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod4,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 4G";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod5,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 5G";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad1,1"])      return @"iPad";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,1"])      return @"iPad 2 WiFi";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,2"])      return @"iPad 2 GSM";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,3"])      return @"iPad 2 CDMA";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,4"])      return @"iPad 2 CDMAS";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,5"])      return @"iPad Mini Wifi";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,6"])      return @"iPad Mini (Wi-Fi + Cellular)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,7"])      return @"iPad Mini (Wi-Fi + Cellular MM)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,1"])      return @"iPad 3 WiFi";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,2"])      return @"iPad 3 CDMA";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,3"])      return @"iPad 3 GSM";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,4"])      return @"iPad 4 Wifi";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"i386"])         return @"Simulator";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"x86_64"])       return @"Simulator";
return @"Unknown";
}
```

Comment: My iPhone 6 appears as iPhone7,2 FWIW

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below code as well:-

```
#import <sys/utsname.h> 

NSString* deviceName()
{
    struct utsname systemInfo;
    uname(&systemInfo);

    return [NSString stringWithCString:systemInfo.machine
                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The wall of code in the accepted answer can be vastly cleaned up by using a static dictionary!

```
NSString *platform = [NSString stringWithCString:systemInfo.machine encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSString * result = [@{
  @"iPhone1,1": @"iPhone 1G",
  @"iPhone1,2": @"iPhone 3G",
  @"iPhone2,1": @"iPhone 3GS",
  @"iPhone3,1": @"iPhone 4",
  @"iPhone3,2": @"iPhone 4 CDMA",
  @"iPhone4,1": @"iPhone 4S",
  @"iPhone5,1": @"iPhone 5",
  @"iPhone7,2": @"iPhone 6",
  @"iPod1,1"  : @"iPod Touch 1G",
  @"iPod2,1"  : @"iPod Touch 2G",
  @"iPod3,1"  : @"iPod Touch 3G",
  @"iPod4,1"  : @"iPod Touch 4G",
  @"iPod5,1"  : @"iPod Touch 5G",
  @"iPad1,1"  : @"iPad",
  @"iPad2,1"  : @"iPad 2 WiFi",
  @"iPad2,2"  : @"iPad 2 GSM",
  @"iPad2,3"  : @"iPad 2 CDMA",
  @"iPad2,4"  : @"iPad 2 CDMAS",
  @"iPad2,5"  : @"iPad Mini Wifi",
  @"iPad2,6"  : @"iPad Mini (Wi-Fi + Cellular)",
  @"iPad2,7"  : @"iPad Mini (Wi-Fi + Cellular MM)",
  @"iPad3,1"  : @"iPad 3 WiFi",
  @"iPad3,2"  : @"iPad 3 CDMA",
  @"iPad3,3"  : @"iPad 3 GSM",
  @"iPad3,4"  : @"iPad 4 Wifi",
  @"i386"     : @"Simulator",
  @"x86_64"   : @"Simulator"
} objectForKey:platform];

if (result) {
  return result;
}

return @"Unknown";
```